# SAML 2.0 Authentication Using PHP

Tags: php, saml

We have a website create in PHP and MySQL where users can register and login. Recently my client gave me some 3rd party service/website which also required users to login to access their services. Now, my client wants that if users is already logged-in to our site and when we redirect user to other/3rd party site it should not ask for the password or login again. When I talked to 3rd party site to provide solution for this, they ask me to implement/use SAML 2.0 SSO option to achieve this feature. Though, I heard about auth0 and SAML but I have no idea from where should I start from.

1. Do I have to add something on our website? Like auth0 service?
2. Do I have to ask something from them to implement this? What changes do I need to make ?
3. What will be the steps involve in this, When we redirect user to 3rd party site it will be auto logged-in or something?

Comment: This won't be easy for you, no matter what people tell you here. SAML is a protocol that uses XML to transfer data around. To integrate with it, it means that your site must be able to accept data that contain a SAML request or response. This is where knowledge of SAML protocol kicks in and where you'd want to use a library such as LightSaml or a complete solution such as simpleSAMLphp (simplesamlphp is a dogshit of a codebase, it's even worse that wordpress). I suggest you either pay a consultant or a 3rd party to do this for you, it will be MUCH cheaper and less error prone.

Comment: Having some direct experience with simpleSAMLphp, I can second @N.B. I would suggest using Shibboleth and setting up a localized service with socat or netcat instead if you absolutely have to get this done. This is definitely worth paying a specialist vendor for if you can swing it though. SAML in general is like pulling teeth.

Answer (score 5):

Some confusion here.

Auth0 is an Identity as a Service product, not part of SAML. You've tagged OAuth but that has nothing to do with SAML either. It's a completely different protocol.

What you need is a SAML client-side stack. As you are using PHP, use [simpleSAMLphp](https://simplesamlphp.org/).

As you are the client, you need to implement the SP mode.

If you were intending to use Auth0, use this [sample](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/php).

Then use Auth0 to do the SAML connection to the SAML IDP.

So the path is:

PHP application --> Auth0 --> SAML protocol --> SAML IDP

Just to be clear, use **either** simpleSAMLphp or Auth0.

Comment: "As you are the client, you need to implement the SP mode." Are you sure?. Pierre mentioned that My website will act as an "Identity Provider". Are they same?

Comment: @Gurveer see how confusing this got from the start? Your website needs people to be logged in and another website needs people to be logged in. What happens in reality is that you are the Identity Provider **and** Service Provider. Being an IdP is something you don't want because it expects the implementor to take of security. From experience, and I know what I'm talking about because I work often in this area - you might make such an atrocity that it will be 10x more expensive to fix it than to pay a 3rd party to do it. If you want to do it on your own, it'll take months to do it right.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your customer want you to be a "Identity Provider", so that when the users are loggued to your website, they will autolog to the other 3rs party customer's website.

**Technical Solution : MiniOrange**

I recently did this, connecting my PHP/MySQL app to external customer's intranets with "MiniOrange" SAML Solution.

- more informations here : https://www.miniorange.com/ and https://idp.miniorange.com/
- support : I had many free hours of Skype Support, they are very good, they helped me until it worked !
- installating/pricing : I paid for having an onsite licence (they installed this on my server at zero cost), but you can use the Cloud version (start from 10$/month), and they have Wordpress and other CMS plugins...

---

**Answers to your questions :**

- 1) Do I have to add something on our website? Like auth0 service? :

yes, your website must be a identity provider...

- 2) Do I have to ask something from them to implement this? What changes do I need to make ?

Yes, they have to install and configure a "Service Provider" connector, that will automatically connect to the Identity Provider (your website) with JSON Web Tokens (JWT) for example, check if the user is already connected to your website (if yes, your website return a token, and then the user autologs to the 3rd party website, if not, he's redirected to the SAML login form for instance)...all this process will be invisible for the user.

- 3) What will be the steps involve in this, When we redirect user to 3rd party site it will be auto logged-in or something?

**The process will be like this :**

- the user goes to the 3rd party site
- the "service provider" connector installed in this 3rd party site checks if the user is connected to this 3rd party site. 
  If yes, nothing to do, the user is already connected.
- If not connected, then the user is redirected to your website's login form.
  The user types his login/password, then is redirected to the 3rd party website.
- the 3rd party website (in which the user isn't yet loggued) ask to his "service provider" module to call the "Identity Provider" (ie your website) with JWT Json Web Tokens for example (the communication between the IDP identity provider and the SP Service Provider is invisible for the user in the browser, but if you install "SAML DevTools extension" Chrome extension, you'll see the tokens exchanged between the Identity Provider and the Service Provider)
- As you are connected to your website (being the "identity provider"), then the Identity Provider returns a SAML Response token, that allows the user to automatically connect to the 3rd party website...And that's done, the user is auto-loggued !

Comment: You didn't make it any clearer, and you also added JWT to SAML. Although possible, it's like forcing `sudo apt-get install` on Windows 7.

Comment: agree at 50% with you ! ;-)  But frankly, whatever the answer, is complicated to setup SAML with external customer/partner etc... I proposed MiniOrange SaaS Solution that is both IDP and SP, so if Gurveer has wordpress for instance, can work out of the box !

Comment: Personally, I'm all in for supporting smaller providers opposed to expensive big ones. Using an existing SaaS is definitely WAY better than implementing the protocol from scratch or touching that dog poo "simple"samlphp.

Comment: what is "smaller provider" for you ?

Comment: The ones that don't spend 600 euros for google adwords cpc to get their name out there when you google for "idp" "saml" or "oauth".

Comment: If you're talking about MiniOrange i suggested, not sure they are doing adwords. And they spent 10 Skype hours for setuping my linux server, MiniOrange, doing tests etc...freely...i think Gurveer will be happy to have free help and finally having something working, whatever the solution (if it hasn't an expensive licence of price per user...for me was 1$ per user !)

Comment: What I meant was that I'm totally ok with suggesting providers such as MiniOrange opposed to the ones I won't name :) it's all good, your answer is fine save the part where you'll confuse anyone when you start adding JWT (OAuth's transfer mechanism) to SAML which uses XML for transfer.

Comment: OK i understand better, thanks for your precisions ! Not sure how to re-edit my answer and what to change, i have just experience of SAML with JWT.

Comment: Yes, that's the "newer" way of dealing with SAML, to transfer SAML inside a JWT. However.. you can tell how much confusion that brings to the table, the fact that there are distributed services talking to each other via some tokens is confusing enough, then getting into what's inside a SAML token, how to do SAML over OAuth etc. just wrecks people's focus, unless you work in the field or have experience. Anyway, have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks for your answer N.B . i will see how to improve my answer...have a nice day too ;-)